# How to Click event on AutocompleteTextView list and query to sqlite.(I has a sample code.)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, autocompletetextview

How to click database list on AutocompleteTextView and send value to query sqlite database. Now i can use AutocompleteTextView to show data and when i click it will show Toast. Please help me. It is very imported for me. Sorry for my bad English.

This is my code.

myDBClass.java

```css
package com.myapp;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class myDBClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase";
 
    // Table Name
    private static final String TABLE_GALLERY = "gallery";

 public myDBClass(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  // Create Table Name
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_GALLERY + 
            "(GalleryID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            " Name TEXT(100)," +
            " Path TEXT(100));");
    
     Log.d("CREATE TABLE","Create Table Successfully.");
 } 
 
 
 // Insert Data
 public long InsertData(String strGalleryID, String strName, String strPath) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
   try {
   SQLiteDatabase db;
       db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data
       
       /**
        *  for API 11 and above
   SQLiteStatement insertCmd;
   String strSQL = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_GALLERY
     + "(GalleryID,Name,Path) VALUES (?,?,?)";
   
   insertCmd = db.compileStatement(strSQL);
   insertCmd.bindString(1, strGalleryID);
   insertCmd.bindString(2, strName);
   insertCmd.bindString(3, strPath);
   return insertCmd.executeInsert();
   */
   
         ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
         Val.put("GalleryID", strGalleryID); 
         Val.put("Name", strName);
         Val.put("Path", strPath);
    
   long rows = db.insert(TABLE_GALLERY, null, Val);

   db.close();
   return rows; // return rows inserted.
           
   } catch (Exception e) {
      return -1;
   }

 }
 
 // Select All Data
 public String[] SelectAllData() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
   try {
   String arrData[] = null; 
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data
    
    String strSQL = "SELECT  NAME FROM " + TABLE_GALLERY;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strSQL, null);
    
     if(cursor != null)
     {
     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      arrData = new String[cursor.getCount()];
      /***
       *  [x] = Name
       */
      int i= 0;
      do {    
       arrData[i] = cursor.getString(0);
       i++;
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());      

     }
     }
     cursor.close();
    
    return arrData;
    
   } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
   }

 }
 
 
 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_GALLERY);
        
        // Re Create on method  onCreate
        onCreate(db);
 }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```css
package com.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   
   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
  // get Data from SQLite
  final myDBClass myDb = new myDBClass(this);
  /*
   * for insert statement
  myDb.InsertData("1","Picture 1", "pic_a.png");
  myDb.InsertData("2","Picture 2", "pic_b.png");
  myDb.InsertData("3","Picture 3", "pic_c.png");
  myDb.InsertData("4","Picture 4", "pic_d.png");
  myDb.InsertData("5","Picture 5", "pic_e.png");
  myDb.InsertData("6","Picture 6", "pic_f.png");
  myDb.InsertData("7","Picture 7", "pic_g.png");
  myDb.InsertData("8","Picture 8", "pic_h.png");
  myDb.InsertData("9","Picture 9", "pic_i.png");
  */
  final String [] myData = myDb.SelectAllData();   
  
        // autoCompleteTextView1
        final AutoCompleteTextView autoCom = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, myData);
        
        autoCom.setAdapter(adapter);
        
        // button1
        final Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            String.valueOf("Your Input : " + autoCom.getText().toString()),
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });    
        
   
    } 
    
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this on click event

```
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            myDb.InsertData(actv.getText().toString());

        }
    });
```